# Avoid class and id collisions when writing javascript library

Tags: javascript, css

**Problem**

I am writing a javascript library. Some functions append quite a bunch of elements to the document. I'm choosing not to style these all individually through javascript since it's using up a lot of execution time. Instead, I will give all appended elements one or more specific classnames or ids (difference doesnt matter in this context) and then define the style in a pregenerated stylesheet.

This practice could induce collisions in class/id naming. Imagine a user of the library already having defined a #foo in another stylesheet or a .bar getting defined in a javascript from another library.

A solution to this would be to prefix classnames to minimize the chance of a collision. Although this doesn't reduce the chances of it happening to 0. Would there be another method of avoiding this through javascript?

Comment: Just use the current timestamp and prepend/append it to your id/class name structure. Mix it with some underscores and the probability of collision is way less than yours. ;-)

Comment: I like the idea! Might be a nice thing to fall back on.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use more specific selectors for the elements instead of renaming class names with prefixes and what not. That means that one library can have the same class name as another one:

HTML

```
<div class="lib1 someClass"></div>
<div class="lib2 someClass"></div>
```

CSS

```
.lib1.someClass {color: green;}
.lib2.someClass {color: black; font-size: 14px;}
```

or using parents:

HTML

```
<div class="lib1">
    <div class="someClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="lib2">
    <div class="someClass"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lib1 .someClass {color: green;}
.lib2 .someClass {color: black; font-size: 14px;}
```

etc... It can get complicated in case you have `.someClass` defined and if it has some rules that are not defined (thus not overridden) inside the library rules, but it's still easily fixed by using a reset sheet for each library.

I'd suggest not doing this with IDs because you might end up having duplicate IDs on one page.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSchultheiss! It's technically avoidable with the parenting version having only one block each (`<div id="lib1">`) but I'd still never risk it as that's not what IDs are for.

Comment: This is a good idea! But I don't feel like it is a complete solution. What if library 1 would be one from an unknown source? Another possible problem would be that I didn't understand your solution (which is even more possible)

Comment: Thank you. I thought you were writing your own libraries... but since it's not the case: you don't stand a chance unless you load the libraries in a specific order, and go fix element by element, writing fixes into your own CSS file. There's just no way around it.

Comment: I am writing my own, but a user could be using another one which is unknown. Thanks for the tips though. I think they might come in handy!

Comment: Well, then it comes to how much power are you willing to give to the user? You can make your library with strong specificities that the user will have a hard time overriding them... or you can use weak specificities and let the user take over. I don't know what you're building, but you can't control something like that coming from several people unless you sandbox them.

Comment: Oh that must be the answer! I can do something like setCSSPrefix(prefix) and then it generates the stylesheet accordingly. If a user bumps into a collision, the prefix can be modified. If you can edit this into your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Or simply put user's id as a parent element id (like I've shown you in the 2nd example) and never worry about prefixes - that way the user will only be able to modify their own sandbox which inherits rules from your libraries. I really don't like the idea of prefixes because HTML is used to build the markup/structure, not CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can be 100% sure that your ids and classes referenced by any library user code.
So prefix is one solution to minimize the chances.
You can have your prefixes more like namespaces style.
Also one other solution which may not be helpful in your case is to have your generated html inside and iframe.
hint: reading about how to build javascript/html widget may give you some more ideas.

Comment: An iframe seems to be a solution, yet a very ancient one. It would act like a kind of sandbox. Any ideas on where to find more info on these kind of methods?

Comment: search for building html/javascript widgets, something like this http://www.stefanwienert.de/blog/2013/10/15/intro-on-making-a-javascript-widget/ may give you some ideas

Comment: I googled for "build widget using javascript avoid css conflict" and it gave me some good results

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting.

Comment: @Olesma yes, this is the namespace idea